# Changing name/comment on GPG key/uids without losing signatures?

Tags: pgp, gnupg

Over the years I've accumulated a few keys.  When I generated them, and when I added various uids to them, I didn't use the 'comment' feature wisely.

At this point I would like to correct that and update just the comment field on each of the uids -- but without losing the signatures that they have accumulated.  No eddress change, no name change, just the comments on the uids.

Can this be done without having to adduid/{del,rev}uid for each one and losing the signatures?

Comment: This was a while ago, but I'm curious, what did you consider unwise about your use of “comment”?

Comment: When I created some of my keys, I wasn't as forward-looking as I should have been in describing the UIDs; I didn't have a plan for formatting them consistently.  As time has passed, some of the comments on older keys no longer apply.  *E.g.*, they were created in a specific environment [such as describing my association with my emplyer at the time], but now have a wider/different scope.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Incoming signatures always point to a UID. UIDs cannot be modified, only revoked. If you want to change one, it will have to get signed again. If you revoke a UID, you will lose all incoming signatures.

UIDs are simple strings usually adhering to the pattern `Name (comment) <mail@example.org>`, and the signature is created over the whole string including the comment.

Imagine you could change UIDs without losing signatures. You could just change your name to another, and pretend to be this guy *and* be certified for this name at the same time. Same applies to comment information which is also certified.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realise the comment was part of the immutable key UID.